# When can I use "being"?

Tags: grammaticality

> If two paths have the same relevant slice with output **being** the slicing criteria, then they have the same input-output relation.

I am not sure where we use *being*. Can we use *being* after the person or object to describe?

> Jim, **being** a lovely boy, is liked by all his friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second example is a perfectly fine example of participial phrase.

> Being a lovely boy, Jim is liked by all his friends.

I assume the first sentence is missing a *the*.

> If two paths have the same relevant slice with the output being the slicing criteria, then they have the same input-output relation.

I don't understand what the sentence means, but you probably mean the following:

> If two paths have the same relevant slice when the output is the slicing criteria, then they have the same input-output relation.

Comment: I don't see a problem with "the" being omitted in the first sentence. One could consider it elided, or simply that "output" is uncountable.

Comment: Yup, *output* is fine without the definite article.

Answer (score 1):

Both the examples you gave sound natural to me.

Other examples:

I like being at home.

Being kind to each other is important.

Reading, being so important in learning other subjects, must be mastered early.